# Scala user input for 2d array

Tags: scala

I am trying out a scala code to take user input in 2D array. However, it throws me `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Code:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) 
    {
        // INPUT [uncomment & modify if required]
        val N: Int = scala.io.StdIn.readLine.toInt
        
        val A= Array.ofDim[Int](N, N)
        
        for(i<-0 to N)
        {
            for(j<- 0 to N)
            {
                // Accessing the values
                A(i) = readLine.split(" ").map(_.toInt)
            }
            //println()
        }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, make sure you share all the code.

Comment: You are iterating  over both `i` and `j` but each iteration is setting a whole line of the array so the `j` iteration is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the code you need to try:

```
object MyObject {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val N: Int = scala.io.StdIn.readLine().toInt

    val A = Array.ofDim[Int](N, N)

    for (i <- 0 to N - 1) {
      A(i) = scala.io.StdIn.readLine().split(" ").map(_.toInt)

    }
    println("A echo:")
    A.foreach(row => {
      println()
      row.foreach(item => print(item + " "))
    })

  }

}
```